# Why are discrete state Hidden Markov Models far more popular than continuous state HMMs?

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I am planning to use a Poisson HMM to model the long-memory serial correlation in my data, and my first thought was to use a mean-reverting continuous state, something like a univariate Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.

But from reading more about it HMMs, it seems that using a continuous state is very uncommon.  Why is a discrete state almost always used?  Are there practical advantages?  The contiouous state seems like a more natural representation to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discrete HMMs are so popular because there exist a variety of nice iterative algorithms such that it is possible to evaluate the likelihood term, which is often needed in estimation algorithms.

In general, there are essentially only two classes of models for which the likelihood in such state space models can be computed exactly: linear Gaussian models, for which the famous Kalman techniques exist, and when X is a finite state space, like the HMM you suggested above. For other models these quantities are typically intractable.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  If I'm planning to use MCMC for calibration, then would that eliminate the advantage discrete states have over continuous ones?

Comment: It is not really an advantage but necessary in 'classic' MCMC to evaluate the likelihood term - so I cannot really comment on this. There has been more research in this area (Check Particle MCMC) where you approximate the likelihood term for the current parameter; here it is possible to extend the scope of possible state space models, but the computation time takes quite a bit longer in my experience.